# Syncing tasks with exchange server

Tags: 2.2-froyo, sync, exchange, exchange-tasks

I've recently upgraded from a Windows Mobile 6.1 phone to a desire, and there is one feature that I miss and that's the ability to sync tasks with my exchange server.  What are other people's, low cost solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Nitrodesk's [TouchDown](http://www.nitrodesk.com/dk_touchdownFeatures.aspx) for that. It does the full Exchange experience. Not free, but not too horrible. I really liked it -- but ultimately uninstalled it as my current android phone is a little gimpy on processor power...

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go, at least they do a free trial :)