# Sync Exchange 2010 notes, tasks and reminders

Tags: 2.2-froyo, sync, exchange, notes, exchange-tasks

My HTC Incredible S phone runs Android 2.2, and has the ability to sync e-mail, calendar and contacts with our Exchange 2010 Server at work.

Tasks, notes and e-mail reminders, however, aren't synced out-of-the-box.

I've been looking, but can't seem to find any lightweight apps on the Google Play Store that can fill this gap.

Does anyone know of such a product?

If a lightweight one does not exist, what would you recommend I do to sync these items? I'd prefer using the built-in e-mail, calendar and contact apps, and would rather avoid bloatware such as TouchDown.

*I found [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8124/syncing-tasks-with-exchange-server) which somewhat addresses this, but doesn't mention e-mail reminders and notes.*

Comment: Update: task synchronization is now included after a system update. However, e-mail reminders and notes remain unsupported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked a number of products and I have got to say Touchdown by Nitrodesk always comes out on top. I have just returned to Android after a short spell with WP7 and fogot how much I relied on Touchdown. My favourite is the fact it will read out emails, which is useful!

Comment: Does TouchDown sync notes? (from the "Notes" tab in Outlook)